# I can't pick the Search bar value and use to search in other website

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm having a problem, I want to search something on my website and when I click in the button, it should take the search value and go to the website I want and search the same think I put in the search bar of my website but now I get this problem.

I have this html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta name="ROBOTS" content="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW" />
<style type="text/css">
    #tfheader{
        background-color:#c3dfef;
    }
    #tfnewsearch{
        float:right;
        padding:20px;
    }
    .tftextinput2{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 5px 15px;
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size:14px;
        color:#666;
        border:1px solid #0076a3; border-right:0px;
        border-top-left-radius: 5px 5px;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 5px 5px;
    }
    .tfbutton2 {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 5px 7px;
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size:14px;
        font-weight:bold;
        outline: none;
        cursor: pointer;
        text-align: center;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #ffffff;
        border: solid 1px #0076a3; border-right:0px;
        background: #0095cd;
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#00adee), to(#0078a5));
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #00adee,  #0078a5);
        border-top-right-radius: 5px 5px;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 5px 5px;
    }
    .tfbutton2:hover {
        text-decoration: none;
        background: #007ead;
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#0095cc), to(#00678e));
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #0095cc,  #00678e);
    }
    .tfbutton2::-moz-focus-inner {
      border: 0;
    }
    .tfclear{
        clear:both;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- HTML for SEARCH BAR -->
    <div id="tfheader">
        <form id="tfnewsearch" method="get" action="https://spyse.com/target/domain/">
                <input type="text" id="tfq" class="tftextinput2" name="q" size="21" maxlength="120" value="Search our website"><input type="submit" value=">" class="tfbutton2">
        </form>
        <div class="tfclear"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And this JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function(){ 
    var submitbutton = document.getElementById("tfq");
    if(submitbutton.addEventListener){
        submitbutton.addEventListener("click", function() {
            if (submitbutton.value == 'Search our website'){
                submitbutton.value = '';
            }
        });
    }
}
</script>
```

When I search for **sapo.pt** on my website the result is **https://spyse.com/target/domain?q=sapo.pt**, and my objective is to get **https://spyse.com/target/domain/sapo.pt**, how can I take of the **?q=** and put **/sapo.pt**?

Answer (score 0):

You can use onsubmit attribute and set the action inside a function for example:

```
    <form id="tfnewsearch" method="get" onsubmit="onSubmit()">
            <input type="text" id="tfq" class="tftextinput2" name="q" size="21" maxlength="120" value="Search our website">
            <input type="submit" value=">" class="tfbutton2">
    </form>
```

Your JavaScript function will look like this:

```
function onSubmit(){
    var action_src = "https://spyse.com/target/domain/" + document.getElementById("tfq").value;
    var your_form = document.getElementById('tfnewsearch');
    your_form.action = action_src ;
}
```

Comment: It didn't work, now it stay on my page and it does nothing.

Comment: The form id was not correct. I have updated the `onSubmit` function. Please try again.